# 行間を小さくするにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

**前提・実現したいこと**

Ruby on rails ユーザー登録のフォームを作成中です。 
Bootstrapを用いて作成しているのですが、 
「パスワード」欄と「確認用パスワード」欄の間が 
不自然に長くひらいてしまっております。 
[こちら](https://gyazo.com/711bb1c22f5ece95e0ffbe7318ea1f48)をご参照下さい。

**解決したいこと**

この行間を縮めるためにはどのような方法がありますでしょうか？ 
何卒ご教示頂きたくお願い致します。

---

**コード**

**app>view>users>registrations>new.html.erb**

```
          <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url:session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">ユーザー登録</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 separator social-login-box"> <br />
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/users/auth/facebook" class="btn facebook btn-block" role="button">Log in using Facebook</a>
                            <br />
                            <a href="http://localhost:3000/users/auth/github" class="btn twitter btn-block" role="button">Log in using Github</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 login-box">
                            <form role="form">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                 <div class="field">
                                  <%= f.label :email %><br />
                                  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
                                          </div>
                                     <!--</div>-->
                                      <!-- <div class="input-group">-->
                                      <div class="field">
                                        <%= f.label :password %></br>
                                        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
                                       </div>
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　       　　　<div class="field">
   　　　　　　　　　　　　　        　　　　 <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    　　　　　　　　　　　　　        　　　　<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　</div>
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　</div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <div class="row">

                       <div class="col-xs-6">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success">
                                <span class="btn-label">-->
                                 <div class="actions">
                                 <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
                                <!--</button>-->
                                 </div><% end %>
                                <!--</span>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
         </div>
 　　　</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
.container {min-width:1200px;}
.social-login-box {max-width:300px;}
.btn-label {
    position: relative;left: -12px;display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;}
.btn-labeled {padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;}
.input-group { margin-bottom:5px; }
.separator { border-right: 1px solid #dfdfe0; }
.facebook,.twitter { min-width:170px; }
.facebook { background-color:#354E84;color:#fff; }
.twitter { background-color:#00A5E3;color:#fff; }
.facebook:hover,.twitter:hover { color:#fff; }
</style>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".social-login-box").height( $(".login-box").height() - 20 );
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ソースコードに多量の全角スペースが含まれています。
それらが表示されていませんか？
[image: 全角スペース]

Comment: ありがとうございます！ケアレスミスでしたが、大変助かりました^^

Comment: よかったです～。
質問が未解決のままなのでお時間あるときにこの回答を承認いただけますか？
解決済みであることが他のユーザーから見て分かるようになります。